# how to split string into an array and sort them

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

i am working on a module where i have stored string in a column separated by comma(,) and i have split the string into an array and added the array into drop down, but when i am doing this with multiple columns, its not sorting the array in dropdown

here is the code

```
   $pp=DB::table('gcp_projects')->where('niche','!=',' ')->where('niche','!=','')->where('niche','!=',null)->orderBy('niche')->pluck('niche');
$testing=explode(",",$pp);


$arr=array();
$tttt=array();
for($i=0;$i<=count($pp);$i++)
{
 $arr= explode(",",$pp);
 $temp = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/", "", $arr);
$tttt=array_unique($temp);
sort($tttt);

}
```

Comment: You're looping through the array `$pp` but in the loop you're still using `$pp`. You would need to use `$pp[$i]` for it to explode on the right item.

Comment: `$tttt` will always have the value of the last iteration of the for loop, I don't think this is what you want. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `where('niche','!=',null)` You don't check for `NULL` this way. Use `whereNotNull()`. Also, what's the point of this question? What are you sorting? Your input and expected output?

Comment: thanks for the feedback, i have stored multiple niche (3 niche per column) i have to get these niche seperated and sort it in a dropdown list, but its showing half sorted and half unsorted

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

// Use preg_split() function 
$string = "123,456,78,000"; 
$str_arr = preg_split ("/\,/", $string); 
print_r($str_arr); 

// use of explode 
$string = "123,46,78,000"; 
$str_arr = explode (",", $string); 
print_r($str_arr); 
?>
```

you can do it like this and use sort option like

```
$values = array ("zercggj.co.uk", "lkjhg.org.au", "qqxze.org.au",
                 "bfhgj.co.uk", "sdfgh.org.uk");

echo "<br>input:<br>";
foreach ($values as $host) echo "$host<br>";

// create a suitable structure
foreach ($values as $host)
{
    $split = explode('.', $host, 2);
    $printable[$split[1]][] = $split[0];
}

// sort by domains
asort ($printable);

// output
echo "<br>sorted:<br>";
foreach ($printable as $domain => $hosts)
{
    echo "domain: $domain<br>";

    // sort hosts within the current domain
    asort ($hosts);

    // display them
    foreach ($hosts as $host)
        echo "--- $host<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So Far i found this solution which is working for me

```
$pp=DB::table('gcp_projects')->whereNotNull('niche')->orderBy('niche')->pluck('niche')->toArray();


$aa=implode(',',$pp);

$myArray = explode(',', $aa);
$im=implode(' ',$myArray);
$ex=explode(' ',$im);
$tttt=array_unique($ex);
 sort($tttt);
 $str = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/", "", $tttt);
  $result = array_filter($str);
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to mention orderby ASC OR DESC

`orderBy('created_at', 'asc')` Or `orderBy('created_at', 'asc')`